# Perl - Undefined subroutine for tan

Tags: perl

Having an issue since don't understand why it's not working for tan, but is fine to work for cos and sin. I would assume the issue is that it's undefined, hence the error message but why exactly does cos and sin work and not tan? How would I then define a tan method? Sorry for the newbie question, I'm just trying to work out Perl.

Error:

```
Undefined subroutine &Slic3r::Print::SupportMaterial::tan called at C:/Users/owner/Documents/Slic3r/lib/Slic3r/Print/SupportMaterial.pm line 945.
```

Tan Code:

```
my $min_angle = 40;
my $min_radian = deg2rad($min_angle);
my $b = tan($min_radian);
@Z=map{$_/$b} @Z;
```

Cos and Sin Code:

```
Polygon->new(map [ $circle_radius * cos $_, $circle_radius * sin $_ ]
```

Edit: Realised that a subroutine would need a function, however when looking at the Perl script I'm trying to integrate with the module, it works fine and doesn't have a method, just declared tan.

Comment: Are you using any module?? This is your complete code (include libraries you might using)?? Just with this peace of code seams you are trying to use `map` in a empty array. If `@Z` is defined, where, when and how you define `@Z`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sin` and `cos` are [builtin Perl functions](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#Numeric-functions), but `tan` is not. This is easily remedied with a simple declaration

```
sub tan { sin($_[0]) / cos($_[0]) }
```

or import a module that defines the tangent function

```
use Math::Trig;
```

Comment: `atan` is missing too, but `atan2` is present. Perl is strange sometimes.